# How to replace only few characters from a string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field `urn_sem.studentid` that I'd like to replace a few characters in; for example:

- `ABC/2011/BCOMH_NC/I/12` → `ABC/2011/BCOMH/I/12`
- `ABC/2011/BCOMH_NC/I/24` → `ABC/2011/BCOMH/I/24`

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(studentid, 'KNC/2011/BCOMH_NC/', ' KNC/2011/BCOMH/')
  FROM urn_sem
```

but it doesn't show the new value.

Comment: What do you mean by "*replace function is not working*"?  More detail, please.

Comment: I am using this command : select replace(studentid , 'KNC/2011/BCOMH_NC/', ' KNC/2011/BCOMH/') from urn_sem

Comment: And why is that not working?  What results do you get vs what you expected?

Comment: I thought it will change the string but it didn't. then i realized it is select query. But still, i didn't show me the changed result. How can I change them ?

Comment: Your examples have `ABC`, but your query has `KNC`. Is that intentional? Maybe you need to just replace `/2011/BCOMH_NC/` with `/2011/BCOMH/`?

Comment: Yeah. This is what I actually want to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this:

```
update urn_sem
    set studentid = REPLACE(studentid, 'KNC/2011/BCOMH_NC/', ' KNC/2011/BCOMH/')
    where studentid like '%KNC/2011/BCOMH_NC/%'
```

The `WHERE` clause is optional.  It ensures that the replace is only on rows that change.

Answer (score 0):

And this sample query does not work?
    SELECT REPLACE (studentid, '_', '') FROM urn_sem